# TabHost color changed between Android versions

Tags: android, android-tabhost

i've noticed that the default look of tabs has changed between Android versions (see screenshot). I like the first version better, but i need to set my android target to version 8 (android 2.2) so that app2sd works. but then i have the darker backgrounds. how can i switch to the old one? setting the background color manually produces ugly results

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Since TabView is a standard widget, it likely relies on a system resource in android.R (or similar.) Because the theme was changed, you would have to manually extract the old images from older android source, copy them to your project, and hook them up to your TabView.

Remember that if your app were able to run on earlier versions of android, on certain custom ROMs, or phones that deviate from the standard android UI, it would look different on each unless you manually set it up to use a specific skin set.